# SilverStripe 3.2 upgrade UploadField doesn't show files

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm updating a SilverStripe site from 3.0 to 3.2. However after the upgrade the `UploadField` on certain Page types doesn't show related files.

**Solution.php**

```
public static $many_many = array (
    "LinkedDocuments" => "File"
);

public function getCMSFields() {

    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    if ($this->ID != 0) {
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Documents", UploadField::create("LinkedDocuments")->setFolderName("assets/solutions/" . $this->URLSegment));
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

**File Extension**

```
class SolutionFileExtenstion extends DataExtension {
    private static $belongs_many_many = array('Solutions' => 'Solution');
}
```

The `Solution_LinkedDocuments` table appears fine. The files still work in the front-end. The only problem is the `UplaodField` is blank, so resaving the page deletes linked files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problme turned out to be a corrupt database table. Not sure why the links were still working in the front end, but I wrote a task to re-link the files based on filename form the pre-upgrade copy of the DB and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't quickly spot anything else wrong except this:

```
public static $many_many = array (
    "LinkedDocuments" => "File"
);
```

the 3.2 contains major changes as previous versions didn't follow semantic version.

On 3.1 static variables need to be declared as a private static to work right

```
private static $many_many = array (
    "LinkedDocuments" => "File"
);
```

See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/changelogs/3.1.0/#upgrading#statics-in-custom-page-classes-need-to-be-private.

From the documentation:

"Most statics defined in SiteTree and DataObject are affected, for example: $db, $has_one, $has_many, $many_many, $defaults, $allowed_children. The same goes for statics defined in ContentController, e.g. $allowed_actions."

Also review the change logs for until 3.1.9 and https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/upgrading/ .

So that is at least one issue you have. Also there are many deprecated functions also that you might be using so you need to watch out for them. Personally I haven't run anything on 3.2 yet and can't see anything directly wrong on the UploadField usage, but I can't test that at the moment.

Anyways you should have seen PHP errors appearing due to deprecated functions and especially for the change of private vs public variables.

Apparently you haven't so I suggest you setting the site in development server to dev mode AND setting PHP error level to E_ALL and display_errors on .

Or review the PHP error logs on the server directly.

Comment: Thanks for catching the public declaration, someohw I missed that one. But that;s not it. New pages work fine, it's just existing pages, and only that relation, The $many_many relation added by the Gallery module works just fine. Error logs are coming up blank, just the few warning I already dealt with.

Comment: Tracked the issue down to a corrupt database table,

Comment: Hmm.. weird that it was corrupted. But glad you found the issue! Thought did you try to run the /dev/tasks/FilesystemSyncTask . Would that fix the table also? Also you might want to run that on dev first :)